# Can't switch back to Classic Gmail and I hate it

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, inbox-by-gmail

I also have two Gmail accounts, I opened both on Google Chrome. One has the option for "Go back to classic Gmail" in setting button. But another account, automatically changed to "New version of Gmail" today, and there is NO OPTION for "Go back to classic Gmail" in this setting button.

I visited this [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail), but no solution found.

Since I hate this new version, can we/I move to the classic version of Gmail?

> If possible, could you please help me return to classic Gmail version.

Answer (score 3):

> To switch to the new Gmail version, click on the gear in the upper
>   right-hand corner of the Gmail page, and click 'Try the new Gmail.'
>   You can use the same process to switch back to the old version of
>   Gmail as well.

But this lasts only for a while. The new version is the only available soon, you can only decide to switch now, not later by Google.

Comment: I think people are NOT ACCEPTING this new version of Gmail. Google should rethink about it. Are they listing feedbacks?

Comment: I hope they listening. I switched to the new version and had to learn everything again. After a while, I became familiar with it.